# Не работает Module32First() c++

Tags: c++

Имеется вот такой код:

```
void get_m(const char* m_name, DWORD pid)
{

    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid);

    MODULEENTRY32 m_entry;

    if (Module32First(hSnap, &m_entry))
    {
        std::cout << m_entry.szModule << (DWORD)m_entry.modBaseAddr << std::endl;
        while (Module32Next(hSnap, &m_entry))
        {
            std::cout << m_entry.szModule << (DWORD)m_entry.modBaseAddr << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "failed";
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
```

Он выводит список модулей запущенного процесса и их адреса. Но проблемы начинаются еще на стадии вызова функции `Module32First`, и в итоге выводится `failed`, хотя программа должна работать дальше и делать вышесказанное. Не могли бы вы подсказать, что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Comment: The calling application must set the dwSize member of MODULEENTRY32 to the size, in bytes, of the structure. (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-module32first#remarks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обычного перечисления модулей программы, функции API `Module32First/Next()` слишком громоздки, поскольку требуют цикла. Для этих целей лучше использовать `EnumerateLoadedModules()` из библиотеки Dbghelp.dll. Она за один вызов возвращает информацию сразу обо всех модулях. [Описание здесь..](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-enumerateloadedmodules)